# Loop through mailitem body not working

Tags: vba, loops, outlook

I need to find a string within an email body. 
The word I am looking for is usually displayed in the body's mailitem like this:

```
Country:                USA
```

I have this loop to find the beginning of a string:

```
Sub GetFirstString()

lBody = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Body
lWords = "Country"

If InStr(1, lBody, lWords) > 0 Then
    Do While Mid(lBody, (InStr(1, lBody, lWords) + Len(lWords) + j), 1) = " " Or _
             Mid(lBody, (InStr(1, lBody, lWords) + Len(lWords) + j), 1) = ":"
        j = j + 1
    Loop
lBeginning = J

Else
    MsgBox "No results"
End If

End Sub
```

I must be missing something here, because the code will always exit the loop even if the condition is reached. Example: the current string is " ", but it always exits the loop when it should continue due to the first condition:

```
Mid(lBody, (InStr(1, lBody, lWords) + Len(lWords) + j), 1) = " "
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a special character that looks like a space, but isn't. My guess is Chr$(160).  Here's a rewrite that will isolate the USA part of the message.

```
Public Sub GetFirstString()

    Dim sBody As String
    Dim sMsg As String
    Dim vaSplit As Variant
    Dim vaLines As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Const sWORDS As String = "Country:"

    sBody = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Body

    'Split the body into lines
    vaLines = Split(sBody, vbNewLine)

    'Loop through the lines
    For i = LBound(vaLines) To UBound(vaLines)
        'If the line has the words
        If InStr(1, vaLines(i), sWORDS) > 0 Then

            'split the line on the words
            vaSplit = Split(vaLines(i), sWORDS)

            'Get rid of any spaces
            sMsg = Replace(vaSplit(UBound(vaSplit)), Space(1), vbNullString)

            'Get rid of any special characters
            sMsg = Replace(sMsg, Chr$(160), vbNullString)

            'Once found, exit the loop because we only want the first one
            Exit For
        Else
            sMsg = "No results"
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox sMsg

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess you are right. 
What does Chr$(160) stands for?
Would it work if I wrote ..... = Chr$(160)    ?

Comment: Character 160 is a non-breaking space. You see it a lot in HTML, but not in normal text files that use Character 32 - that's the space you're used to. You could simple add Chr$(160) to your code, but I thought I'd show you a different way.  Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the Word object model to get the job done. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the message body. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information. For example, a raw sketch:

```
  mail.GetInspector().WordEditor
```